# Custom antD Drawer and onClose not working

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have 2 problems

1. `OnClose` function is not working in the drawer component. However, `esc` key can close it.
2. I want to customise the title. (add an icon (i) to the left of it and a subheading). I tried using the prop extra, but it would only shift everything to the right

```
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
      const showDrawer = () => {
        setVisible(true);
      };
    
      const onClose = () => {
        console.log('hi')
        setVisible(false);
      };

    <Drawer
      title="Grouped"
      width={"35%"}
      placement="right"                      
      closable={false}
      onClose={onClose}
      visible={visible}
      extra={
        <Space>
          <div>hi</div>
          <span onClick={onClose}><img src={crossImg}/></span>             
        </Space>
      }
      >
         <div className="multi-country-drawer">
           {multiCountryGroup()}
         </div>
    </Drawer>
```

edit : title can be a reactnode, can be customized

Comment: 1) closable={false} this will hide the close button from the top. check whether the onClick on the span is overlapped by some other CSS or not.
2) Title prop can be a react component. so you can pass your own component to title

Comment: title is solved, but onClose is not overlapped with any css. Moreover it's printing in the console.

Comment: Then maybe some other code in the component is causing the issue, could check it in a useEffect whether the value of visible changes in component or not. or please code the full component code

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on the [Documentation](https://ant.design/components/drawer/), your code looks fine except for the `closeable` prop which would make the (x) button invisible when set to false.
2. The `title` prop can be a `ReactNode` so you can easily add an Icon as so:

```
<Drawer
  title={
    <div>
      <RightOutlined />
      <span>Hello world</span>
     </div>
   }
   placement="right"
   onClose={onClose}
   visible={visible}
   >
     <p>Some contents...</p>
</Drawer>
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-17-0-alpha-3-forked-gjyu3?file=/index.js